# Trying to make sequential executing of futures. What is wrong?

Tags: scala, futuretask

I am trying to execute function which returns Future sequentially

So, I have a collection

```
  val in = Seq(1, 1, -1, -2, 3, -4, 5, 6, 7, -1, -2, -9, 1, 2, 2)
```

and function to process every int in this collection

```
  def intToFuture(int: Int): Future[Int] = {
    Future {
      println(s"Running function $int")
      Thread.sleep(1500)
      int * 100
    }
  }
```

I need to implement logic that process collection by portions of parallel processing.
Get first n elements, multiply each to 100 in parallel, then get next n elements and do the same... etc.

What I have done(after I read some posts on this site) is, I implement two functions

1)to process a batch of calculations

```
  def processBatch(ints: Seq[Int])(f: Int => Future[Int]): Future[Seq[Int]] = {
    Future.sequence(ints.map(f))
  }
```

2)and second, which apply to process iteratively

```
  def batchTraverse(in: Seq[Int], size: Int)(f: Int => Future[Int]): Future[Seq[Int]] = {
    val grs = in.grouped(size).toList
    def loop(l: Seq[Seq[Int]]): Future[Seq[Int]] = {
      l match {
        case Nil =>
          Future.successful(l.flatten)//? flatten
        case head :: tail =>
          println("head="+head)
          processBatch(head)(f).flatMap{
            s => loop(tail).map{ t =>
              s.appendedAll(t)
            }
          }
      }
    }
    loop(grs)
  }
```

And start this by

```
  val fs: Future[Seq[Int]] = batchTraverse(in, 3)(intToFuture)

  fs.onComplete{
    f => println(f)
  }
```

As a result, it makes only one iteration, where have I mistaken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function actually seems to works fine, what is likely happening is your program is terminating before the future gets a chance to complete, thus you're only seeing the first iteration. By adding an await to your code I was able to get things to work.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val fs: Future[Seq[Int]] = batchTraverse(in, 3)(intToFuture)

fs.onComplete{
  f => println(f)
}

Await.result(fs, Duration.Inf)
```

You'll likely want a duration that smaller than `Duration.Inf` as this will wait forever for the future to complete. Doing this I was able to get the following output:

```
head=List(1, 1, -1)
Running function 1
Running function 1
Running function -1
head=List(-2, 3, -4)
Running function -4
Running function 3
Running function -2
head=List(5, 6, 7)
Running function 7
Running function 6
Running function 5
head=List(-1, -2, -9)
Running function -9
Running function -2
Running function -1
head=List(1, 2, 2)
Running function 2
Running function 2
Running function 1
Success(List(100, 100, -100, -200, 300, -400, 500, 600, 700, -100, -200, -900, 100, 200, 200))
```

Comment: thank you a lot, I am really glad to know that I have done all I needed, thanks!